# How to add a landing page to a mkdocs doc site using mkdocs-material?

Tags: material-ui, mkdocs

I'm trying to create a landing page similar to how mkdocs-material's doc site (https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/) has. I am using mkdocs-material for my docs site.

Answer (score 22):

#### How?

You will need to use a custom template for a specific page (e.g. home page) and providing the implementation for this template. So for the home page you are looking for this file: [.overrides/home.html](https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/blob/master/material/.overrides/home.html). You'll want to copy it over to your own overrides directory or take [my example as reference](https://github.com/binbashar/le-ref-architecture-doc/tree/master/material/overrides). Make sure you've set your [`custom_dir` in `mkdocs.yml`](https://github.com/binbashar/le-ref-architecture-doc/blob/e6d39a68ce3c48484e108fa54beb51baad0ad53e/mkdocs.yml#L18):

```
 theme:
   custom_dir: material
 ...
```

In the front matter of your [`index.md`](https://github.com/binbashar/le-ref-architecture-doc/blob/master/docs/index.md), you need to specify the template to use:

```
---
title: Title
template: home.html
---
```

#### Important Consideration

You **need** a newline at the end of your md file. If you don't have one, the content will not display. I guess it's processed as having null content if you don't include the newline.

#### Ref Links

- https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material/issues/1996.
- https://github.com/binbashar/le-ref-architecture-doc.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can find the source code / setup of that site in its respository.
https://github.com/squidfunk/mkdocs-material
This should be a good example.